# Restructuring collection items in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, collections, laravel-collection

I've got the following Laravel collection of between 800 and 4000 items:

```php
[
  {
    "date": "2017-05-26",
    "departure_time": "14:50:00",
    "arrival_time": "09:20:02",
    "departure_place_id": 16
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-05-26",
    "departure_time": "15:20:00",
    "arrival_time": "15:20:00",
    "departure_place_id": 15
  },
  ...
]
```

I need to merge always merge two items of the collection into one. So that a collection of 10 items, after merge, is a collection of 5 items with the follwing structure.

```php
[
  {
     "date": "2017-05-26",
     "departure_time": "14:50:00", // from first item
     "arrival_time": "15:20:00", // from second item
     "departure_place_id": 16,  // from first item
     "arrival_place_id": 15 // from second item
  },
  ...
]
```

As you can see I need to merge data from two consecutive items to one.

I already tried two extend use Laravels [custom collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-collections#custom-collections) feature but cannot really achieve what I want.

Any clue?

Comment: If nothing else will not help, than you can make it with transforming to array, make operations, and than resulting array transform to collection. But I hope someone will post solution without this "arrays" step.

Comment: Totally right @Autista_z .. I am also looking for a solution without using arrays. Hope there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it by using laravel collection [chunk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-chunk)

```
 public function formatCollection($collection)
 {
  $results = [];
     foreach (collect($collection)->chunk(2) as $chunk)
     {
         $results[] = [
             'date' => $chunk[0]['date'],
             'departure_time' => $chunk[0]['departure_time'],
             'arrival_time' => $chunk[1]['arrival_time'],
             'departure_place_id'=> $chunk[0]['departure_place_id'],
             'arrival_place_id' => $chunk[1]['departure_place_id']
         ];
     }

    return collect($results);
 }
```

> Call this function to format the data

Comment: I wanted to avoid using arrays. Any idea how make this only using the collection and also returning a collection without the array?

Comment: you can return json, `return response()->json($results);`

Comment: You can read the documentation also, it will return array only, you can again return your json by converting like above

Comment: I have changed my answer, please check now returning collection, please check and upvote, if it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

IMO, if you only had two items, you should create a class which will "merge" your two items in one as you do.

Collection are made to treat a collection of items, so 1 to N items not only two.

Comment: The collection has between 800 and 4000 items. It is just an example in my post.

Comment: Oh well ! 
So for this usage (i dealt with a similar case : summarizing road events for a fleet managmement company).

I create a decorator (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) around the collection object to manipulate it

Comment: Yes, could be sth. to consider. I'll have a look into decorators - I was rather looking for a solution that would restructure the items when creating the collection so that a second touch of the collection could be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

After the tip from @Vikash with using `chunk()` and some research I came up with the following solution which suits my needs best:

```php
public function convert() : \Illuminate\Support\Collection 
{
    /** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection $collection */
    $collection = $this->cruise->where('line_id', $lineId)->get();

    return $collection->chunk(2)->map(function ($chunk) {
                /** @var Collection $chunk */
                return [
                    'date' => $chunk->first()->date,
                    'downriver' => $chunk->last()->departure_place_id < $this->departure_place_id,
                    'departure_time' => $chunk->first()->departure_time,
                    'arrival_time' => $chunk->last()->departure_time,
                    'departure_place_id' => $chunk->first()->departure_place_id,
                    'arrival_place_id' => $chunk->last()->departure_place_id,
                ];
            });
}
```

I put that into a repository which is a nice way to decouple the logic. It utilizes the `collection` [functions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#available-methods) instead of dealing with arrays which I definately wanted to avoid.